# Solar neutrino problem: LUNA

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics

One of the most solutions that was thought to resolve the solar neutrino problem for energetic neutrino from B decay (in the pp chain) was a resonance in $^3He(^3He,2p)^4He$ that would had suppressed the reaction $^3He(^4He,\gamma)^7Be$. Why a resonance would suppresse the other reaction?
Then they did the experiment at LUNA and found no resonance. So no suppression
[image]

Comment: Just as a comment on notation, the parenthesis in the $A(B,C)D$ notation are generally used to distinguish between those reactants or products with experimentally measured energy and/or momenta (inside) and those for which these quantities are not measured (outside). With that understanding it doesn't make sense to use such a notation in a case where *nothing* is measured.